How can I stop this part oscillating - HFBR-2555AFZ
hopefully I can pose this question well.
I have a fiberoptic communications circuit as part of a larger device which I designed which has worked really well with HFBR-2505AZ, but unfortunately I can no longer source this part as it has been made obsolete. After a bit of searching I came across HFBR-2555AFZ - which, albeit faster, is pin compatible and even shares an identical datasheet example circuit (which, is what I used in my original circuit to make use of this part).

(note I am aware the datasheet states AFBR but this is taken directly from the HFBR datasheet from the Broadcom site, I believe it to be a typo in the datasheet)
For some reason, however, even with the output floating, the device goes into oscillation, this is what I see on the output pin regardless of what is connected to it or if it is left floating:

I have tried the following so far:

Different power supplies feeding this circuit, just incase it was something funky with noise injection from my SMPS (ruled out)
Adding more decoupling capacitance between pins 6 and 7
Pull up and pull down as well as greater load on the output

...and unfortunately no joy. It confuses me that I have exactly the example circuit in the datasheet and yet it still oscillates. (FYI, this is on a PCB, not a breadboard).
I really am tearing my hair out with this because the 2505AZ worked perfectly and the 2555AFZ just oscillates and only receives garbled messages - as well as outputting continuous rubbish. Literally any suggestions or troubleshooting advice is greatly appreciated :)
Link to Datasheet
TIA

What part specifically are you using for C4 in the schematic? Can you probe the voltage across it?

Also, can you verify that R2 is really not more than 2.7Ω?

I am using Panasonic ERJ-HP6J2R7V, I will knock the resistor off now and double check it.

C4 is a kemet C0603C104K4RACTU, I'm measuring 4.991V across it

Also, that is a ceramic capacitor, and the schematic calls for a polarized cap; so they might have though of aluminium electrolytics with high series resistance, to dampen the oscillations between the variable load (the receiver) and the capacitor.

You can try the following: take C4 and put it on the other side of R2.

Good shout, I will try that, tested the resistance and it's 2.7R

I just tried moving the capacitor, no joy, and then switching to an electrolytic... Again no joy, same behaviour as soon as light hits the receiver it goes into oscillation - I won't lie this is a real head-scratcher... Thank you for the suggestions

by the way, in case you don't get this to run for some reason, if you're doing Mb/s, then chances are any SFP Gigabit ethernet fiber transceiver module for 1000Base-·X would possibly do. Here's a project that allows you to connect just any TTL (or LVTTL) signal and switch the device that way – but you must make sure there's always something going on at the input at a minimum frequency (discussion).

This is just 9600 baud serial for a very noisy industrial environment, unfortunately due to legacy requirements an SMA is desirable - but thank you for the suggestion - I'd have considered those if space allowed / suitable fibres were reasonable to have produced.

Are you testing with optical input present or absent? If you're testing without an optical input, I suspect something like an automatic gain control (AGC) circuit chattering, and the issue will likely go away once you supply optical input.

If you've reworked the same PCB, are the ground connections still good? Sorry if it's an obvious suggestion.

Thanks Photon, I've tried both, basically as soon as the optical fibre does anything it goes into oscillation, doesn't matter if you start up with fibres fitted or unfitted.

Cheers Dr Pippik. Two layer board, very simple, compact, entire bottom is unbroken ground plane with a good connection to ground. They don't provide a suggested layout, for three components, I did consider the layout but one would think of it was critical it would be mentioned. I've tried multiple receiver parts and also multiple PCBs (I have 20 here), same issue with all of them.

Ok, I've wired the Rx on its own, dead bug style, no other components, same oscillations...
